# how to pass a list of objects over VF page

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I am new to salesforce and apex.

In my 1st VF page it shows some book names (from DB) and when I want to add more books I put a button in the 1st page and shows all the books from DB in the 2nd page.

If I selected some of the books from page2, I have to add it in the first page with the previous results (books).

How can I do this in APEX Visualforce?

Comment: Check out the Visualforce pages Developer Guide (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf). I think that part about creating a wizard (page 97) will be especially helpful because it passes parameters from one page to another. Also please read about PageReference object.

Answer (score 0):

Two visualforce pages can have the same controller but navigating from page1 to page2 will create another object of that same controller.
To prevent a new object from being created set the setRedirect method of the PageReference class to false, this will preserve the view state and you will have access to same objects from both the pages.